# Create worksheets based on a master worksheet and then rename each tab

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create worksheets from a list of "projects" from a master worksheet. When a worksheet is created I want it to be renamed as the project number from the list.

I found two macros that do the job but I need them to work together.

This one creates tabs and renames them.

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()
    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Invoice Summary").Range("B11")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
        Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count) 'creates a new worksheet
        Sheets(Sheets.Count).Name = MyCell.Value ' renames the new worksheet
    Next MyCell
End Sub
```

This one copies master tab and creates another worksheet.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim ws1 As Worksheet
  Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
  ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there is no worksheet named "Master (2)" in your workbook, this code should work:

```
Sub CreateSheetsFromAList()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")

    Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Sheets("Invoice Summary").Range("B11")
    Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

    For Each MyCell In MyRange
       ws1.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Sheets.Count)
       ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master (2)").Name = MyCell.Value
    Next MyCell

End Sub
```

It does seem odd that there is no worksheet object returned from the Worksheet.Copy method.

One thing to note when using xlDown to get the end range -- if you have zero cells or one cell in your range, xlDown will extend all the way to the last row of the worksheet, which will produce undesirable behavior.  In this case, you'll get an error when attempting to rename the target sheet, but it is something to look out for.

Comment: This macro you gave me works just right, but could you help me with two more things....the new tabs open after the worksheet named "Master" is there a way to open tabs after a different worksheet. Also, when the new tabs get created based on a master tab I want the same name that's naming the new tab appear in a certain cell within the new tab.

Comment: For your first question, yes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837784.asp